# Button Declared in XAML can't be referenced in Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `button` I declare within a `Stack Panel` as I've written below. I want to access the button in my class so I can change the visibility such as `myButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` but it just says `myButton` does not exist. It seems private to the `XAML stack panel` and I don't know why.

`XAML`

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ic">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="12" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="X" Foreground="Red" Width="15" Height="15" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" Click="Remove_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

`Class`

```
myButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; //myButton doesn't exist in current context
```

Comment: This seems like a X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve? Normally you would introduce a property for the visibility and bind your button to that property.

Comment: I have an array, of unknown size, where I run a for loop printing a textblock for each element in the array, and alongside that a button (which is the XAML you see above). The loop runs as long as the number of elements. I ideally want to assign a name to the button so when a certain button next to the textblock is clicked I can act on the textblock. At the moment I can't individually refer to the buttons as they haven't been assigned a unique name as I don't know how to when the quantity of buttons isn't defined. @Lennart

Answer (score 0):

Due to your button being declared within a DataTemplate, you cannot access it directly as with objects declared outside of it. (The DataTemplate provides the information to template your objects when added to the ItemsControl)

If you expect to only have a single , you can remove the whole  object around it and gain access to your Button that way.

If you're planning on having an array of s in your , then you'll have to look into making a search logic like the one from this website:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-access-named-control

Answer (score 0):

This generic extension method will search recursively for child elements of the desired type:

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) 
where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) 
        return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So using that you can use like this `ic.GetChildOfType<Button>();`